# Is Available Ms Graph webhook for Ms Planner?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, microsoft-planner

I am deepening the use of the Ms Graph webhook and for this I must monitor the most common tasks in Ms Planner.

For example, creating a task, registering and/or updating comments on a task. Do you have information if this feature is already enabled in Ms Graph for Ms Planner?

Thanks for the feedback

I was testing some configurations with a different type of resource but at least it did not find documentation about it associated with Ms Planner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webhooks are currently not available for Tasks. This is something we're looking into adding soon. Comments on Tasks are Group Conversations which do support webhooks, so you should be able to detect when a new reply is added to a task with an existing conversation.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am making the subscription (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions) to listen to the conversations of a group. 


This is part of the body that I sent
{
   "changeType": "created",
   "resource": "groups('demo-zzzz-4ab5-8e21-44552255')/conversations",
}

But it returns me:
 "message": "Subscription to a group's 'conversations' is not supported with Application-level permissions.",

I have permissions enabled in my app registration

Group.Read.All | Delegated | Read all groups|Yes| Granted for zzzzz

What may I be missing?

Comment: That is different from this question, you should ask it as a separate question to get the experts on it to see. The error says application permissions are not supported. I'm not sure if this is something planned to be supported there or not.